# Are there Lie groups in fractional dimension?

Tags: lie-groups, fractals

Consider the [Sierpiński triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle). It has dimension $\log_23$.

So does it have any rotational group associated with it? e.g. a *Lie group* $SO(\log_2 3)$ ?

Or are there any such things as *Lie groups* in fractional dimension?

Comment: Are you familiar with how the dimension of a Lie group is defined?

Comment: You are confusing topological dimension and Hausdorff dimension. The latter applies to metric spaces. Let groups, by definition, are topological spaces. Yes, you can equip a Lie group, say, ${\mathbb R}$, with some left-invariant (non-Riemannian) metric so that the Hausdorff dimension will be fractional.

Comment: The fact that there is not a "nice" group action on the Sierpinski gasket is causing me no end of headaches in my life right now.  My suspicion is that, in general, it is going to be very had to find groups which act on spaces with non-integer Hausdorff dimension in manner that is compatible with the topology induced by the metric on those spaces.  There may be some hope for some kind of interesting monoid action, but I wouldn't hold your breath.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: You can take any connected Lie group and snow-flake the distance function induced by any left-invariant Riemannian metric. The result will be an invariant fractal metric.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Indeed.  I am aware of specific constructions which allow one to create specific examples.  My comment was more in line with the fact that there is likely no general construction which will allow one to associate a Lie group like structure to an arbitrary (fractal) set.  By way of example, if one is interested in describing a primitive process in the Sierpinski gasket (from which one obtains a random walk in the continuum limit), then the lack of a group action on the gasket is a problem.

Comment: In general, given an arbitrary set of fractional dimension (which dimension?), I suspect that there is going to be little hope of finding a meaningful symmetry group.  In the case of the attractor of a (sufficiently nice?) iterated function system, there may be a group of quasi- or partial- or [insert adjective here]- symmetries obtained from the monoid structure of the IFS, but even that is a fairly constrained set of examples.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Every finite dimensional locally compact Hausdorff group is locally homeomorphic to a totally disconnected space times $R^n$. This imposes strong restrictions on topology. There are some strong restrictions for transitive actions of locally compact groups on locally path-connected finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That is rather my point.  A metric space must have a very special structure in order for it to be *possible* for a group to act on it in "nice" way.  Most metric spaces lack such a structure. As I read it, the question seems to ask if, given an arbitrary metric space, is it possible to find a group which acts on that space in a "nice" way?  As I noted in my first comment, you are going to be hard pressed to find such a group in general, i.e. it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: It is not obvious to me how to fractionalize something line Lebesgue covering dimension. Integers are hard coded in it’s definition. On the other hand “Inductive Dimension” another topological dimension can be made fractional which ill construct later. The answer isn’t super illuminating it just turns the induction step to an inequality and let’s you add as many fractals as you want to your base case, to end up with an inductive-like dimension that’s also consistent with Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: In general for many suitably nice fractals. You can construct balls of these fractals by asking about the “set of all points of geodesic distance $r$” from a point of your choice. Then you can ask about the set of isometries of this ball. That is the set of continuous maps which preserve the geodesic distances. For even something like the Vicsek fractal you end up with a very complicated group which might even have fractal dimension.

Comment: We don’t have good conventions here as this unanswered question shows: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432880/have-we-discovered-constructions-for-natural-fractional-dimensional-spheres we still need to agree “what are good fractional dimensional spheres” and then ask what are their isometries and then some primitive fractal-lie theory can be built this way

Answer (score 1):

Every Lie group is, by definition, a differentiable manifold. Therefore, its dimension is always a non-negative integer.

Comment: Of course. The question was implying there might be a generalisation of the Lie group concept.

Answer (score 0):

We can have groups that have fractional dimension. Consider the [cantor set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) which consists of all numbers between $0$ and $1$ inclusive such that the base representation that real number does not include the digit 1.
Examples of valid values in the set include $0.02020202…$ the set can be made into a group by considering the following operation applied digit wise:

$$ 0 + 2 = 2 \\ 2 + 0 = 2 \\ 0 + 0 = 0 \\ 2 + 2 = 0 $$

You end up with a group which has exactly 1 element for every element in the Cantor set. This group isn’t continuous with respect to any reasonable metric because the Cantor set is totally disconnected, but this gives at least a good start. There are higher dimensional cantor like sets (such as the vicsek fractal) which are connected and so the resultant group might at least retain that continuity when assembled.

Also depending on how you intrinsically measure distance between elements in a fractal it’s possible to come up with some gnarly looking group operations that start to resemble Lie groups but aren’t because of the fractal dimension. I will expand on this later when I have more time.

Comment: Well, any set can be turned into a group. However that isn't really a satisfactory answer if there is no connection between the group multiplication and the topology.